# Accessing views from superclass

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am trying to centralize my code for handling navigation drawers into a superclass that all activities extend.  The super class itself extends Activity but I can't seem to figure out how to access the subclass's view (findviewbyid returns null).

How can I access the views inflated in CheckinActivity from CommonCode?

Superclass oncreate:

```
public class CommonCode extends Activity{
....
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
super.onCreate(b);
 context=getBaseContext();
```

SubClass

```
public class CheckInActivity extends CommonCode {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is have seperate XMLs for each sub activity, but have all the xml ids of your navigation drawers be the same.

Next, when you start any subclass of your extended activity, pass a bundle with the contextView id - R.layout.MY_SUB_ACTIVITY - in a bundle, and actually set the content view for each sub activity from within your super class.

Afterwards, you can use findViewByID to find your drawers, set them up in the super class, and then just handle your subclass's views from within it's own class.

Your views are likely returning null, because your running your super class's onCreate before your subclass's - therefore setContentView hasn't been called yet (so findViewByID won't work)

EDIT:

Also, you don't HAVE to name all the navigation drawer IDs the same -- I just think it's easier to use an `<include>` tag, to minimize redundancy in your xml files.

For Example:

Subclass -

```
public class InviteActivity extends MainActivity {

public static void openActivity(Activity from_activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(from_activity, InviteActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(MainActivity.KEY_LAYOUT_ID, R.layout.invite_activity);
    bundle.putBoolean(MainActivity.KEY_HAS_LEFT_DRAWER, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(MainActivity.KEY_HAS_RIGHT_DRAWER, false);

    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_MAIN_BUNDLE, bundle);
    from_activity.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      .....

    }
```

SuperClass:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /*
     * Bundle keys specifying if the new activity inheriting from MainActivity
     * has a left and/or right navigation drawer.
     */
    public static final String KEY_MAIN_BUNDLE = "com.smashingboxes.bevii.MAIN_BUNDLE_KEY";
    public static final String KEY_HAS_RIGHT_DRAWER = "com.smashingboxes.bevii.HAS_RIGHT_DRAWER";
    public static final String KEY_HAS_LEFT_DRAWER = "com.smashingboxes.bevii.HAS_LEFT_DRAWER";
    public static final String KEY_LAYOUT_ID = "com.smashingboxes.bevii.LAYOUT_ID_KEY";
    public static final String KEY_SECTION_TITLE = "comm.smashingboxes.bevii.SECTION_TITLE";

    /*
     * Boolean indicators for each activity specifying their active navigation
     * drawers.
     */
    private boolean hasRightDrawer;
    private boolean hasLeftDrawer;

    /* The current activity's layout id for setContentView */
    private String sectionTitle;
    private int contentID;

    /* UI Elements */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    /* Reference to the ActionBar title to toggle text on drawer changes. */
    protected CustomTextView mTitle;

    private ListView mDrawerListLeft;
    private LeftNavigationAdapter leftAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerListRight;
    private LeftMessagesAdapter rightAdapter;

    /**
     * Handles the navigation drawer set up for each class inheriting from main
     * activity. A bundle must be specified indicating the number of navigation
     * drawers present in the activity's UI.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_MAIN_BUNDLE))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Cannot access a subclass of MainActivity without including a main bundle.");

        Bundle mainBundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra(KEY_MAIN_BUNDLE);
        hasRightDrawer = mainBundle.getBoolean(KEY_HAS_RIGHT_DRAWER);
        hasLeftDrawer = mainBundle.getBoolean(KEY_HAS_LEFT_DRAWER);
        contentID = mainBundle.getInt(KEY_LAYOUT_ID);
        sectionTitle = mainBundle.getString(KEY_SECTION_TITLE);

        setContentView(contentID);

        if (hasRightDrawer && hasLeftDrawer) {
            handleLeftNavigationDrawer();
            handleRightNavigationDrawer();
        } else if (hasLeftDrawer) {
            handleLeftNavigationDrawer();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach.  Let me take a tinker and I'll come back to accept this if it works.

Comment: Ok.  Let me know if it's clear enough - I can provide a code example if necessary, but don't want to bother unless it's needed...

Comment: My only confusion right now is that since the Superclass oncreate gets called before the subclass' that means I wont have time to pass in any bundle before the superclass oncreate gets called.  So I'm guessing I'll need to create public methods in super class and call them manually to set up the UI after the subclass oncreate starts?

Comment: getIntent() is the same for the super and subclass -- you get the same bundle that you attached to the intent that started the activity.  Intents can contain multiple bundles, so you could have a MAIN_ACTIVITY_BUNDLE, that has specified extras, and use getIntent.getBundleExtra(MAIN_ACTIVITY_BUNDLE).getExtra...

Comment: Edit with example code.  Also, remember, that after your super class method returns your subclass's onCreate() finishs execution, so just set up its UI within it's own onCreate().  (In response to your last comment)